# call this -(void) from another .m file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How do I call this `-(void){}` (*function, method? sorry, I forgot the terminology*) from another .m file?

I would also like to be able to call it in the local .m file like such `[self closeMenu];`

Here's the `-(void){}` :

```
-(void)closeMenu{

//close the menu

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{

    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; // so it doesn't cut randomly, begins from where it is

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    [menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(menuView.frame.origin.x, -menuView.frame.size.height, menuView.frame.size.width, menuView.frame.size.height)];

}];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the method in a .h file that has the interface.

In YourClass.h

```
@interface YourClass:NSObject
- (void)closeMenu;
@end
```

In YourClass.m

```
@implementation YourClass
- (void)closeMenu
{
    //Close the menu
}
@end
```

Then you have to import (`#import "YourClass.h"`) in the other file that you want to call this method from.

```
#import "YourClass.h"

@implementation OtherClass
- (void)otherMethod
{
    YourClass *foo = [[YourClass alloc] init];
    [foo closeMenu];
}
@end
```

Comment: Then you've made a mistake somewhere else. You need to provide some more information before someone can help you.

Comment: Yes I am also facing this issue. let me explain. I am using xcode 4.3.3 and my senior 4.5. Senior convert the project in to ARC enabled and I checkout it from svn and its working. Now If I modify the existing class EmailSettingsViewController  and add some methods then EmailSettingsViewController class able to calls the method using self but If I created instance of the EmailSettingsViewController class and call the new added method it giving me error "ARC issue , No visible @interface for 'EmailSettingsViewController' declares the selector 'orderNum:CustCode:'"

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you're talking about some kind of a controller method to collapse some kind of a menuView and looks like this is a global menuView that you would like to share with the rest of your App.

Whenever I have "shared" widgets I use a manager for them.

Can you describe the kind of architecture that you're talking about?

Because the dirtiest kind of "Apple Sample code" approach that pops from my mind is to keep a reference to this baby in the App delegate and from anywhere in your App you could do this:

```
MyDelegate * delegate= (MyDelegate)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.myCoolMenuController closeMenu];
```

Hope this works for ya.

Cheers

Comment: Well, I would just like to perform the method from another class file.

Comment: Yeah, you can call these lines from anywhere in your app, the appDelegate is available anywhere.